# Error: Property 'class' of feature '0_0' is missing

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, feature-class, random-forest

Using GEE, I am trying to do a crop-type classification using Random Forest. My training data are two shapefiles I uploaded to GEE and made a FeatureCollection from their geometries. However, it gives me the error that, the Property 'class' of feature '0_0' is missing.I figured out the problem could be from 'null data' and tried to filter them,but then the training data become invalid! any suggestion plz...

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f9bcdeffdf2e6b4b9fb78cfb7b3c5355

```
var coll1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-05-15')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-05-16', '2020-05-31')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll3 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-06-15')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll4 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-06-16', '2020-06-30')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll5 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-07-01', '2020-07-15')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll6 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-07-16', '2020-07-31')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll7 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-08-01', '2020-08-15')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll8 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-08-16', '2020-08-31')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll9 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-09-01', '2020-09-15')
            .filterBounds(ROI);
var coll10 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
            .filterDate('2020-09-16', '2020-09-30')
            .filterBounds(ROI);

print(coll1);
Map.centerObject(ROI,10);

var addNDVI = function(img){
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi);
}

var addNDWI = function(img){
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['B3','B8']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi);
}

var withNDVI1 = coll1.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI2 = coll2.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI3 = coll3.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI4 = coll4.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI5 = coll5.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI6 = coll6.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI7 = coll7.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI8 = coll8.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI9 = coll9.map(addNDVI);
var withNDVI10 = coll10.map(addNDVI);


var with_ndwi1 = withNDVI1.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi2 = withNDVI2.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi3 = withNDVI3.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi4 = withNDVI4.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi5 = withNDVI5.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi6 = withNDVI6.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi7 = withNDVI7.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi8 = withNDVI8.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi9 = withNDVI9.map(addNDWI);
var with_ndwi10 = withNDVI10.map(addNDWI);

print(with_ndwi1,'with_ndwi1');

var image1 = with_ndwi1.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_1','B3_1','B4_1','B8_1','B11_1','B12_1','NDVI_1','NDWI_1']);
var image2 = with_ndwi2.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_2','B3_2','B4_2','B8_2','B11_2','B12_2','NDVI_2','NDWI_2']);
var image3 = with_ndwi3.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_3','B3_3','B4_3','B8_3','B11_3','B12_3','NDVI_3','NDWI_3']);
var image4 = with_ndwi4.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_4','B3_4','B4_4','B8_4','B11_4','B12_4','NDVI_4','NDWI_4']);
var image5 = with_ndwi5.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_5','B3_5','B4_5','B8_5','B11_5','B12_5','NDVI_5','NDWI_5']);
var image6 = with_ndwi6.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_6','B3_6','B4_6','B8_6','B11_6','B12_6','NDVI_6','NDWI_6']);
var image7 = with_ndwi7.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_7','B3_7','B4_7','B8_7','B11_7','B12_7','NDVI_7','NDWI_7']);
var image8 = with_ndwi8.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_8','B3_8','B4_8','B8_8','B11_8','B12_8','NDVI_8','NDWI_8']);
var image9 = with_ndwi9.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_9','B3_9','B4_9','B8_9','B11_9','B12_9','NDVI_9','NDWI_9']);
var image10 = with_ndwi10.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12','NDVI','NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_10','B3_10','B4_10','B8_10','B11_10','B12_10','NDVI_10','NDWI_10']);

///Creating a stacked image with 30m resolution as my training data///
var stacked = image1.addBands([image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7,image8,image9,image10]).clip(ROI).reproject('EPSG:32636', null, 30);
print(stacked,'stacked');

Map.addLayer(stacked,vis,'Stacked');
//print(RICE);

Map.addLayer(RICE,{},'rice',false);
Map.addLayer(MAIZE,{},'maize',false);

////Train sample////
// var gt = rice.merge(Maize);

///try another way of training while using the original polygon////
// Make a FeatureCollection from the hand-made geometries.
// var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection([
//   ee.Feature(RICE, {'class': 0}),
//   ee.Feature(MAIZE, {'class': 1}),

// ]);

var rice = RICE.map(function(feature){
  return ee.Feature(feature).set('class', 0);
});
var maize = MAIZE.map(function(feature){
  return ee.Feature(feature).set('class', 1);
});
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection([rice, maize]);
var sample=rice.merge(maize)



// Generate 100 random pt sample
var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(
    {region: sample, points: 100,seed: 0, maxError: 1});



// Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = stacked.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: randomPoints,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 30
});


// // Filter out the null property values and try again.
// var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
//   ee.Filter.notNull(training.propertyNames())
// );


var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(128)
                  .train({
                    features:training , 
                    classProperty: 'class'
                    
                  });

var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified');
Map.addLayer(classified,
        {min: 0, max:1 , palette: ['yellow','green']},
           'classification',false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random points from your polygons doesn't contain the `class` property. You could add it back with this:

```
var referenceData = ee.Join.saveFirst('polygon')
  .apply({
    primary: randomPoints, 
    secondary: sample, 
    condition: ee.Filter.intersects({leftField: '.geo', rightField: '.geo'})
  })
  .map(function (feature) {
    var polygon = ee.Feature(feature.get('polygon'))
    return feature
      .copyProperties(polygon)
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a7b9167095e6c11ab74d926a53dc79f4

Comment: It worked. Thank you.